# Zapier: E164 GB/UK Mobile Number Parsing, Can it be done using Python/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, twilio, zapier

*Hello,*

Currently trying to parse a UK mobile number from a web form into E164 format using Zapier. This is so in turn I can trigger a text using a Twilio and Zapier integration.

Twilio only takes the [E164](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#phone-numbers) format, however most users will enter their number as:

"07000111333"
or
"447000111333"

Zapier currently has a parsing service which converts to E164 but this only works on US numbers. Is it possible to parse using a "GB" code, exactly as Google's android phone parsing javascript library does? and if so, is anyone aware how this can be integrated into a Zapier workflow? Using the "Code" element for example which lets you run Python or Javascript.

**In short, how can I parse UK mobile numbers on Zapier into E164 format?**

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As you've tagged this Python you could use the [Python phonenumbers library](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers). It's a port of Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber), which I can only guess is what Google use in Android.

According to the README, it's as easy as the following:

```
>>> import phonenumbers
>>> number = phonenumbers.parse("07000111333", "GB")
>>> print number
Country Code: 44 National Number: 7000111333 Leading Zero: False
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you for that tip! Going to try and look at this over the next few days and see if I can integrate the Python code with Zapier.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, this isn't going to work on Zapier. I didn't realise it had a code running Zap these days! Sadly it doesn't run external dependencies like this. It shouldn't be too hard to replicate the Zapier behaviour with a bit of Python, the phonenumbers library and the Twilio API though.

Comment: Alternatively, could I recommend you ask specifically for the user's country code in a separate field. [Countries don't map directly to country codes and vice versa](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md). You could then use the Python code Zap to merge the two together and send on to Twilio.